# Sending picked image to another view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimage, mapkit

Im working with Mapkit. In the leftcalloutaccessory, there is a small image, thats been taken from the userlocation. In the rightcalloutaccesory, there is a button, that will make a segue, to another viewcontroller, so the user can see the image in large size. 
The issue is - it is random which saved image, that will be shown on the another view.

```
class ImageAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation  {
var image: UIImage?
}
```

Then in the Map view controller it looks like this

```
var imageAnnotations: [ImageAnnotation] = []
var sendImage: UIImageView!

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    guard let annotation = annotation as? ImageAnnotation else {
        return nil
    }

    let identifier = "MyCustomAnnotation"


    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)


    if annotationView == nil {

        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true


    } else {

        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    let image = UIImage(named: "advance.png")
    let button = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button


    let detailImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    detailImage.image = annotation.image
    sendImage.image = annotation.image
    annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = detailImage

    return annotationView
}
```

It works. Its showing the right image in every annotation. But "pickedimage", can be every saved images.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    for annotation in imageAnnotations {
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    gettingData()
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
{
    if (view.annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
        print("Clicked annotation ")
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            sendImage.image = UIImage(named: "advance.png")
        }
    }
}

func buttonPressed (sender: UIButton!) {

    let currentImage: UIImage = sender.imageForState(.Normal)!

    sendImage.image = currentImage

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowLargeImage", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowLargeImage" {
        let goToImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ImageViewController

        goToImageViewController.newImage = sendImage.image
    }
}
```

Comment: remove these two lines in `let currentImage: UIImage = sender.imageForState(.Normal)!

    sendImage.image = currentImage` in here `func buttonPressed (sender: UIButton!)`

Comment: Still saying  'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'. Can't figure out where its happening

Comment: ok in which line you are seen the error

Comment: I can make the app run correctly when i remove the sendImage.image = annotation.image. But it will crash when i push the button

Comment: sendImage.image = annotation.image - it for leftCalloutAccessoryView and  this for  if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            sendImage.image = UIImage(named: "advance.png")
        }  rightCalloutAccessoryView

Comment: you need both or you need any one direction

Comment: Looks like what i did. Do i need to change something?

Comment: i  dont kow ur project concept , that the reason in here I get liitle confused on here `buttonPressed`

Comment: Ok, i removed the buttonPressed. Now it prints "Clicked Annotation" but won't crash

Comment: you need anything else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119011/discussion-between-jonask-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In destination view controller:

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var finalImage: UIImageView! // assume that its your imageViewname

    var newImage: UIImage! // assume that it is pass Image

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let img = newImage
         {
        finalImage.image = img
         }
    }
}
```

In Source view controller:

```
 //create one Common ImageView
 var sendImage: UIImageView!

func buttonPressed (sender: UIButton!) {


self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowLargeImage", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "ShowLargeImage" {
    let goToImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ImageViewController

    goToImageViewController.newImage = sendImage.image // directly pass the image no need of converson
}
}
```

at the same time add here also

```
let detailImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
detailImage.image = annotation.image
sendImage.image = annotation.image
annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = detailImage
```

**updated answer**

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) 
{
 if (view.annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
   print("Clicked annotation ")
if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
     sendImage.image  = UIImage(named: "advance.png")
}
}

}
```

Comment: It works! I had to make the detailImage outside the function. Thanks a lot, been bothering me for a long time!

Comment: @jonask   - choice is yours , do well

Comment: Oh wait. There will be a new issue. Now it is random which image that will be in the leftcalloutaccessory.

Comment: @jonask - left call accessory contains  one  image  correct

Comment: What do i have to do?

Comment: let currentImage: UIImage = sender.imageForState(.Normal) - It want me to put '!' after (.Normal) And when i do that, the app will crash and tells me unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @jonask - ok  put '!' and try once

Comment: Then the app crash and tells me 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

Comment: Hmmm still saying 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'